# Type-traits experimentation, SFINAE seems not to be working, whines about the absence of something in the form of an error

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm trying to use C++11, rather than using C++ as C++98 (I come from C) and I've hit type-traits, now rather than jumping in to the standard I thought I'd try and solve the problem.

Usually I'd use inheritance to add methods based on the type, and rely on the user, but I want to use traits, now I don't expect the end user to use my "custom ones", this is because it's an experiment.

I started by creating a True and a False type, as so:

```
struct True {
    static const bool value = true;
};

struct False {
    static const bool value = false;
};
```

Then my `enable_if` definition, which I understand to use the fact that a struct or class is both a struct (in the C sense, has a size and such) and a namespace, as so:

```
template<bool B,class T>
struct EnableIf {};

template<class T>
struct EnableIf<true,T> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

I now expect that only `EnableIf` with `true` to have a "namespace type member" (if I may) called "type" which is whatever the template T is. This seems to work.

I understand that the false/default case should "silently fail" when I try and access `EnableIf<false,T>::type` because of the absence of `type`

I'm pretty sure everything so far is right, but I'm just being verbose.

**My test case**

I've chosen a list as my testing ground (again not using the standard set because I am investigating) Usually I use a class hierarchy to do this, I'd have a `list` that could do nothing more than act as an array, the only extra member would be `int find(T*);` because a T* is a T's identity.

Then I'd extend that to have a `int find(T&);` `int find(T&,int)` and `int count(T&)` and this'd use == to compare Ts. This is what I mean by leaving it up to the user, they could chose the list they wanted based on what /they/ knew about the type.

I want to use `EnableIf` (later `std::enable_if` when I feel more confident) to do this instead, that way when the template is stamped out functionality is only `enable`d if the type is able to be used that way.

**List definition**

```
template<class T>
class List {
public:
    typedef typename T::hasEquality hasEquality;
    virtual ~List() {}
    virtual T& operator[](int index) =0;
    virtual const T& operator[](int index) const =0;
    virtual void append(T*) =0;
    virtual int length() const =0;
    virtual
        typename EnableIf<hasEquality::value, bool>::type
    operator==(const List<T>& rhs) const {
        if(length() == rhs.length()) {
            for(int k=0;k!=length();k++) {
                if(!((*this)[k] == rhs[k])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    virtual
        typename EnableIf<T::hasEquality::value, int>::type
        count(const T& what) const =0;
};
```

It's a list not a set so order matters. You can see that this should make `hasEquality` transitive in the sense that:

*if T has the concept of equality than a list of T has the concept of equality also*

I then go on to implement a singly-linked-list.

**Testing types**

```
class A {
public:
    A(int value) { val = value; }
    typedef True hasEquality;
    bool operator==(const A& rhs) const {
        if(val == rhs.val) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    int val;
};

class B {
public:
    typedef False hasEquality;
};
```

**Results**

```
int main(int,char**) {
    LinkedList<A> listA;
    listA.append(new A(6));
    A a(6);
    std::cout<<"there are "<<listA.count(a)<<" of them\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As you'd expect this works. My first test initially included B but that causes problems.

```
int main(int,char**) {
    LinkedList<A> listA;
    listA.append(new A(6));
    A a(6);
    std::cout<<"there are "<<listA.count(a)<<" of them\n";

    LinkedList<B> listB;

    return 0;
}
```

This does not, it fails with:

```
src/main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class List<B>’:
src/main.cpp:77:7:   required from ‘class LinkedList<B>’
src/main.cpp:176:16:   required from here
src/main.cpp:59:2: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct EnableIf<false, bool>’
  operator==(const List<T>& rhs) const {
  ^
src/main.cpp:73:3: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct EnableIf<false, int>’
   count(const T& what) const =0;
   ^
src/main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class LinkedList<B>’:
src/main.cpp:176:16:   required from here
src/main.cpp:134:3: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct EnableIf<false, int>’
   count(const T& what) const {
   ^
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 1
```

For some reason it puts the error marker after the typename line, it is unhappy everywhere I use an `EnableIf` with `false`

I am really not sure why this is, it is right, there is no `type`, but this is by design!

**Research**

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

To quote that:

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Mine differs only by name and the default T being void, adding this to mine (as I expected) does not fix the problem.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/SFINAE

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/enable-if

Confirm my thoughts.

**Bonus questions**

**constexpr and static**

Initially I tried `struct False { constexpr bool operator==(bool what) { return !what; } };` and the same for `True`;

But this did not work, and I cannot use the word "static" to qualify operator==, but I could have used a method called `constexpr static bool is(bool what);` for the same effect, why doesn't constexpr imply static?

In my mind constexprs never really exist, and the design is sort of like the opposite of virtual, there's nothing that says you cannot use an instance to call a static method, I've just checked C++03 standard, section 9.4 confirms this, has this changed?

**SFINAE**

Would it be possible to use SFINAE to assume `False` when `hasMember` has not been defined? I understand this wont work for the fundamental types and such, this is an experiment. I will not use these techniques in production stuff until I am confident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
virtual
    typename EnableIf<T::hasEquality::value, int>::type
    count(const T& what) const =0;
```

You hit another example where generic programming (templates) and object oriented programming styles conflict.

SFINAE is a metaprogramming technique that works with templates. Despite the appearence (the use of `T`), the function declared above is not a template. It's a normal function inside a template class. The template type parameter `T` is a parameter of `List` and **not** of `count`.

For instance, the following is an example of SFINAE:

```
template<class T>
class List {
public:
template<class T>
class List {
public:
    // ...
    template <typename U>
    typename EnableIf<std::is_same<U, T>::value && U::hasEquality::value, int>::type
    count(const U& what) const { std::cout << "1\n"; }

    template <typename U>
    typename EnableIf<std::is_same<U, T>::value && !U::hasEquality::value, int>::type
        count(const U& what) const { std::cout << "2\n"; }
};

};

int main() {
    A a(1);
    B b;
    List<A> la;
    la.count(a); // outputs 1
    List<B> lb;
    lb.count(b); // ouputs 2
}
```

Notice that the two `count`s are now a templates (parametrized on `U`). Both are active only if `T` is the same type as `U`. This is a workaround to accept `T` only (it's not perfect, for instance, it discards implicit conversions). The first requires, in addition, that `U::hasEquality::value == true` and the second requires the opposite.

The key point here is that SFINAE works on templates.

But as you can see I changed your design and made `count` non virtual. Unfortunately, you cannot make the `count` functions above virtual because template functions cannot be virtual.

The basic issue is as follows. Template functions are instanciated only when they are called. So when the compiler parses `List` (my version) it doesn't know yet all the instantiations of `count` that are going to exist.

For each virtual function there should be an entry in the virtual table and when the  compiler parses `List` it must know how many entries there are in the virtual table.

Hence, on one hand, when parsing `List` the compiler doesn't know the number of template instancitaions and, on the other hand, it must know the number of virtual functions. The conclusion is that template functions cannot be virtual.

Answer (score 2):

SFIANE only applies to template argument deduction and overload resolution of functions. For classes you can instead use template specialization.  In your case you could do template specialization something like this (no `EnableIf` required):

```
template <typename T, typename = typename T::hasEquality>
class List;

template <typename T>
class List<T, False> {
    // no operator==
};

template <typename T>
class List<T, True> {
public:
    // ...
    bool operator==(const List<T,True>& rhs) const {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

As to your `constexpr` question, you can have `constexpr` constructors that create compile time object you can then call `constexpr` member functions on that will run at compile time, so it doesn't make sense for `constexpr` to imply `static`.

---

It's too late for me to be answering questions it seems. You can use SFINAE to conditionally enable a member function, it just has to be a template function. So you can change your `operator==` to

```
template <typename = typename EnableIf<T::hasEquality::value, void>::type>
bool operator==(const List<T>& rhs) const {
    // ...
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: I could probably avoid copy-and-pasting all member definitions, but what about the declarations? Does this break DRY? Do you think "enable_if" has a misleading name?